# Are changes in the tax code for individuals usually retroactive to the beginning of the year, or not?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax

With the new administration, there is a potential for changes in the tax code.  The one that interests me the most is the possibility that the rate for long-term capital gains (now 20%, maximum) will be raised to the rate for ordinary income which might be as high as 39.6%.

I seem to remember that changes in tax rates were not retroactive to before the change was proposed in the bill.  Was this usually the case, and is it likely to be the case in 2021, or is it a coin toss at this stage?

Comment: There was a very similar question not too long ago but I can't find it. Typically changes to tax law affect future tax-years but there have been some exceptions. I'd say the exceptions are usually more edge-case and not any sweeping reforms since the IRS needs time to adjust documentation/forms.

Comment: @HartCO: it was https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/132393/can-a-newly-elected-president-congress-change-tax-law-effective-the-year-they but it now 404s at my (low) rep; you may still have access